# Why @Binding Property causes not releated init every time?

Tags: swiftui, combine

It's a bug confused me for all day, I make a demo for my case, all is just a list and a detail.

**Room.swift**

```
struct Room: Identifiable {

    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

**RoomListModel.swift**

```
class RoomListModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rooms: [Room] = [
        Room(id: 1, name: "Room A"),
        Room(id: 2, name: "Room B"),
        Room(id: 3, name: "Room C"),
    ]
}
```

**RoomList.swift**

```
struct RoomList: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = RoomListModel()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model.rooms.indices) { index in
                    RoomRow(room: self.$model.rooms[index])
                }
            }
            .listStyle( GroupedListStyle() )
        }
    }
}
```

**RoomRow.swift**

```
struct RoomRow: View {

    @Binding var room: Room

    init(room: Binding<Room>) {
        print("initing RoomRow: " + room.name.wrappedValue)
        self._room = room
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: RoomDetail(room: $room)
        ) {
            Text(room.name)
        }
    }
}
```

**RoomDetail.swift**

```
struct RoomDetail: View {

    @Binding var room: Room

    init(room: Binding<Room>) {
        print("initing RoomDetail: " + room.name.wrappedValue)
        self._room = room
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(room.name)
    }
}
```

For convenience, I add print in init.

When List load, all the RoomRow and RoomDetail are inited, that is OK.

```
initing RoomRow: Room A
initing RoomDetail: Room A
initing RoomRow: Room B
initing RoomDetail: Room B
initing RoomRow: Room C
```

But when I trigger to one of RowDetail, all the RoomDetails is inited again, But I just go to one, not all of them, **WHY** all the RoomDetails are inited, and **AGAIN**?

```
initing RoomDetail: Room C
initing RoomDetail: Room A
initing RoomDetail: Room B
```

I don't know why, but found one solution, I removed all @Binding property, and It's OK, but **WHY** `@Binding` will cause unreleated init?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue, using Xcode 11.0 and iOS 13 everything seems fine.

Comment: @Eluss I checked just now, Xcode is 11.1 and iOS is 13.1, and I upload a demo, please retry.  https://github.com/cuimingda/ForEachTest